# SQL/PHP Compare two dates as seconds

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have a field called **lastTime** which holds the current time when I make a query to my table using NOW().
It's stored as **datetime** in my table.

I then retrieve this value at some point from the table with a query and it returns a string.

```
$lastTime = retrieve_lasttime_from_table();
$curTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if($curTime - $lastTime >= 5){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

So basically I'm trying to see if 5 seconds have passed.
What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

strtotime() is the best way to find the difference

```
if((strtotime($curTime) - strtotime($lastTime)) >= 5){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and below example would probably work.

<strike>`if(strtotime($lastTime) - (strtotime($curTime)) >= 5){`</strike>

```
if((strtotime($curTime) - strtotime($lastTime)) >= 5){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

<strike>**Note: I switched the positions of `$lastTime` and `$curTime`, as I guess you need to check, when Current Time is greater than or equal to 5 seconds from Last time.**</strike>